# Override property and call base version

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to override a property of a base class and call a base version of the property from the override (TypeScript  [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20get%20a()%3A%20number%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%201%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20B%20extends%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20get%20a()%3A%20number%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20super.a%20%2B%201%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)):

```
class A {
    public get a(): number {
        return 1;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public get a(): number {
        return super.a + 1; // error TS2340: Only public and protected methods of the base class are accessible via the 'super' keyword.
    }
}
```

But the TypeScript compiler returns an error:

> error TS2340: Only public and protected methods of the base class are
>   accessible via the 'super' keyword.

How to override a property of a base class and call a base version of the property from the override?

Comment: Seems that typescript doesn't have a notion of property accessor types, only property and method types. Not sure how you'd get around this one.

Comment: This seems to work for me with TypeScript 3.

Answer (score 2):

Try super['a']. super.a is not allowed. Refer this link:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4465